why ts cannot narrow type in such situation
I think when the switch statment is executed, the kind of a and the kind of b are always equal. So when the kind of a is '1', the type of b will be B1. But it's not the case: errors occur.
interface A1 {
    kind: '1'
}

interface A2 {
    kind: '2'
}

type A = A1 | A2

interface B1 {
    kind: '1',
    data: number
}

interface B2 {
    kind: '2',
    name: string,
}

type B = B1 | B2

function foo(a: A, b: B) {
    if(a.kind !== b.kind) {
        return;
    }

    switch(a.kind) {
        case '1':
            const _1 = b.data
            break;
        case '2':
            const _2 = b.name
            break;
    }
}

error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'B'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'B2'.

30             const _1 = b.data
                            ~~~~

i check the doc of typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html
and chat with gpt, but there is no progress.
similar question: Is there way to narrow function parameters witch have same union types signature to exactly same subtypes by generic type

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question here: is it really why TypeScript can't narrow here, as the title implies? If so, then the answer is at ms/TS#54252 and I'd be happy to flesh that out into an answer here. Or it it "how can I refactor my code to get narrowing to work"? If so, then the answer might be one of the several already posted below (or any of a number of possible ways to rewrite things.) Please [edit] to clarify.

@jcalz thank you. The link points to a very valuable discussion, which answers the question in more detail.

yet you accepted an existing answer, so... I guess you're not really asking "why"? Could you [edit] the question title then to be more in line with the answer you accepted?

@jcalz Sorry, I seldom ask questions on StackOverflow.
Yes, I know roughly how to make ts feel comfortable. What I want to ask is why ts can't do this. The answer I accepted also mentioned "You cannot narrow on one variable (a.kind) to affect another variable (b).", which is similar to the "control flow analysis is not multivariate" mentioned by the ts repo member in the link you provided. If you use an answer instead of a comment, I might be more inclined to accept your answer.

You cannot narrow on one variable (a.kind) to affect another variable (b). Also logical narrowing (a.kind === b.kind should narrow a.kind to mean same as b.kind for the remainder of the code) is not supported.
Simplest would be to narrow on b.kind (why wouldn't you?) or store b.kind in kind right after you do the check so its clear which "kind" would be same for a or b.
interface A1 {
    kind: '1'
}

interface A2 {
    kind: '2'
}

type A = A1 | A2

interface B1 {
    kind: '1',
    data: number
}

interface B2 {
    kind: '2',
    name: string,
}

type B = B1 | B2

function foo(a: A, b: B) {
    if(a.kind !== b.kind) {
        return;
    }
    const kind = b.kind;

    switch(kind) {
        case '1':
            const _1 = b.data
            break;
        case '2':
            const _2 = b.name
            break;
    }
}


TS always gives me very intuitive results, which also makes me have excessive expectations for it. Thanks for your answer.

@icewalker this doesn't narrow a though

@AlexanderNenashev This code is more like a supplement to express that we can only narrow a and b separately. But yes, accept this answer may be somewhat ambiguous with the question. Answering "cannot narrow on one variable to affect another" and attaching the link mentioned in jcalz's comments may be a better answer to this question.

@icewalker Updated answer. Cross narrowing is not supported (was already mentioned), but now I've also added logical narrowing is not supported :)
